# how to save data from Bootstrap Modal using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to save data inserted from a modal. Now i have a view called users where i show the list of users.now if admin clicks on add more users it opens a bootstap modal where i have a field called no of users requested. So whatever value the admin fills that must be save into database. I am confused on how to save this.

> Edited...................................................

After reseller logs in he can request more users to admin so i created that modal to request the users required so i want to store the number of users required by that reseller along with his/her key

My Controller is :

```
public function index ()
{
     $usertype=$this->session->userdata('usertype');
    if($usertype ==="reseller")
    {
    $key= $this->session->userdata('key');

    $this->db->where("key",$this->session->userdata('key'));        
    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();


    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'reseller/user/index';
    $this->load->view('reseller/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('permission');

}

}
```

My view Is :

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request More Users</a>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add the number of users you want</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Number Of Users</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="spinnerInput" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question unclear but will give it ago. On your form you need to have form action if you do not have it then will not work. make sure also url helper is auto loaded.

Docs http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Also would look into codeigniter form validation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

And form helper

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

`<form action="<?php echo base_url('controller-name/function');?>" method="post" method="post">`

You may need to use index.php in base_url();

`<form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/controller-name/function');?>">`

View

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request More Users</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Add the number of users you want</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url('controller-name/request');?>">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Number Of Users</label>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="spinnerInput" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Model

```
class User_m extend CI_Model {

function request_user() {
    $data = array(
        'key' => $this->session->userdata('key'),
        'total_user' => $this->get_total(), // create a column in table
        'username' => $this->input->post('username')
    );

    $this->db->insert('table', $data);
}

function request_update_user() {
    $data = array(
        'total_user' => $this->get_total() // create a column in table
        'username' => $this->input->post('username')
    );
    $this->db->where('key', $this->session->userdata('key'));
    $this->db->update('table', $data);
}

function get() {
    $this->db->where('key', $this->session->userdata('key'));
    $query = $this->db->get('table');
    return $query->result_array();
}

function get_total() {
   $this->db->where('key', $this->session->userdata('key'));
   $query = $this->db->get('table');
   return $query->num_rows();
}

}
```

Controller

```
class Reseller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_m');
}

public function index () {

    $usertype = $this->session->userdata('usertype');

    if($usertype == "reseller") {

    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'reseller/user/index';
    $this->load->view('reseller/_layout_main', $this->data);

} else {

    $this->load->view('permission');
}

}

public function request() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('modal_view');

    } else {
        $this->user_model->request_user();
        redirect('your_controller');
    }
}

}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to save the data to database? i have table called user_request and fields are id,key,date i am too confused here.

Comment: i have went too confused please help if you can

Comment: You should read through the user guides first I have added sample model function but you would need to hash password.

Comment: i can use site_url instead of base url?

Comment: Yeah but can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: Not recommend on views. On controllers ok.

Comment: the password is just dummy that would be removed i just want to store the num of user requested by reseller

Comment: So my modal shows text box for entering the user;s requested then it will go to controller then model will save the data right?

Comment: Is the $key there session id? you should of said all this in your question.

Comment: Yes key is stored in session as well

Comment: so should i be passing the key in model and controller both right

Comment: You need to be more clear what your after and explain it in your main question. It's bit confusing now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90873/discussion-between-rajan-and-wolfgang1983).

Comment: after reseller logs in he can request more users to admin so i created that modal to request the users required
so i want to store the number of users required by that reseller along with
his/her key

Comment: I do not think my answer is suited please un-accept it.

Comment: no i think the answer is correct i just need to save the reseller key along with the other data